# Why is the escape "energy" $e=1$ for a massive object in Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, escape-velocity

Being $e$ the quantity found through Killing vector $(-1,0,0,0)$,
$$e = (-1,0,0,0)\,\cdot\,(\dot{t},\dot{r},\dot{\theta},\dot{\phi})$$
For the Schwarzschild metric,
$$e = \left(1 - \frac{2M}{R}\right)\dot{t}.$$

The problem I'm trying to understand says: "A spaceship whose mission is to study the enviroment around a black hole is hovering at a Schwarzschild coordinate radius $R$ outside a spherical black hole of mass $M$. To escape back to infinity, crew must eject a part of the rest mass of the ship to propel the remaining fraction to escape velocity. What is the largest fraction $f$ of the rest mass that can escape to infinity? What happens to this fraction as $R$ approaches $2M$?"

The solution asserts that to escape it must have $e=1$ (using $c=1$). Why is it?

To be considered, the geodesic equation in Schwarzschild is
$$\frac{e^2-1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \dot{r}+V_{eff},$$
where $V_{eff}$ is the effective potential that is a function of $\frac{1}{r}$ and higher orders,
$$
\begin{align}
V_{eff} &=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{-2M}{r}+ \frac{l}{r^2}-\frac{2Ml^2}{r^3} \right),\\
l &= r^2\dot{\phi}.
\end{align}
$$

$l$ is computed as $e$ through the Killing vector $(0,0,0,1)$, $\theta=\pi/2$ due to symmetry.

Comment: Could you provide the complete statement of the problem?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I edited the text to include the full statement.